# Convert UITextField values to strings

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsurl

The point is for someone to enter their ClientID and API into two UITextField's and I'll pass them to a URL. Well I need to convert those to string. I have, but the app is crashing on running. What would be the best way to do this?

My code is below:

```
@interface LogInViewController : UIViewController

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *clientID;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *clientAPI;

@end

@implementation LogInViewController {
    NSString *clientIDToString;
    NSString *clientAPIToString;
}

- (IBAction)signIn:(id)sender {
    clientIDToString = _clientID.text;
    clientAPIToString = _clientAPI.text;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.digitalocean.com/droplets/?client_id=%p&api_key=%p", clientIDToString, clientAPIToString]];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all don't use `%p` but use `%@` in your string and so:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.digitalocean.com/droplets/?client_id=%@&api_key=%@", clientIDToString, clientAPIToString]];
```

this is the reason of the crash.

Second thing: your `@property` should be `weak` and not `strong` because you are using `IBOutlet`.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.digitalocean.com/droplets/?client_id=%p&api_key=%p", clientIDToString, clientAPIToString]];
```

Should be:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.digitalocean.com/droplets/?client_id=%@&api_key=%@", clientIDToString, clientAPIToString]];
```